# Databricks write back to azure synapse error

Tags: databricks, azure-synapse

The following is my code

```scala
df.write \
  .format("com.databricks.spark.sqldw") \
  .option("url", "jdbc:sqlserver://**********.sql.azuresynapse.net:1433;database=********") \
  .option("user","sqladminuser")\
 .option("password","***********") \
.option("forwardSparkAzureStorageCredentials", "true") \
  .option("dbTable", "dbo.testingoutfromdatabricks") \
  .option("tableOptions", "CLUSTERED COLUMNSTORE INDEX, DISTRIBUTION = HASH (_c0)") \
  .option("tempDir", "abfss://********@**********.dfs.core.windows.net/tempfolder/") \
  .save()
```

And I got the following error .

> Not able to validate external location because The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden. [ErrorCode = 105215] [SQLState = S0001]

from the Azure synapse sql pool , I use COPY command from the same blob storage , and successfully load the table ... Anyone got the above error ?

Answer (score 2):

To resolve this issue, make sure Managed Service Identity must be used when attempting to access secured Azure Storage.

Assign `Storage Blob Data Contributor` role to the Azure Synapse Analytics server’s managed identity.

For more details, refer [Write Data from Azure Databricks to Azure Dedicated SQL Pool(formerly SQL DW) using ADLS Gen 2](https://chinnychukwudozie.com/2020/11/13/write-data-from-azure-databricks-to-azure-synapse-analyticsformerly-sql-dw-using-adls-gen-2/).